# ImportError: No module named cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, py2exe

I am using wxpython and matplotlib to develop a software, when I complete my work, I want to convert the python files to `*.exe` file by py2exe, so it can be used in Windows. Here is the `setup.py` file.

```
from distutils.core import setup  
import py2exe  
import sys  
includes = ["encodings", "encodings.*"]    
sys.argv.append("py2exe")  
options = {"py2exe":   { "bundle_files": 1 ,"dll_excludes":["MSVCP90.dll"]}}   
setup(options = options,  
      zipfile=None,   
      console = [{"script":'test.py'}])
```

Then I executed this script by `python setup.py` to generate `test.exe`,and it worked.

When I executed `test.exe` there post an error `ImportError: No module named cycler`

And then, I try to execute `import cycler` in python shell, and there is no error occur. Also, I checked the python directory  `c:/python27/Lib/site-packages/`, and the `cycler-0.9.0-py2.7.egg` file exists here.

How to deal with this problem.

Comment: Same error here but got it after trying to run some matplotlib code on a Debian system.

Answer (score 9):

In case you are using anaconda, use:

```
conda install cycler
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me whereas others (including conda forge) reported condition as satisfied, however, I will mention for benefit of others that PIP install revealed that cython was not installed so this was added pre conda install. Not sure if that made a difference or not, any comments that help me understand more about this much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: FYI: I tried 'conda install cycler', but  did not work. But, 'pip install cycler' did.

Answer (score 7):

`matplotlib` calls `cycler` and it seems `cycler` has not been introduced to `matplotlib`, which is the cause of the above error.

To fix this issue just open Terminal (or command prompt) and try to run the command

`$ sudo pip install cycler` if you have `pip` installed

OR

`$ sudo easy_install -U cycler` if you have `easy_install` installed.

If this command is successfully executed, it should look like `matplotlib` can use it.

Even I had this problem, when I executed this command my problem got solved.

Comment: Somebody should report this as missing dependency of either matplotlib or/and pandas. Since it's still not fixed by default.

Comment: @danger89 nice of you to volunteer (:

Answer (score 0):

On an HPC environment, I solved this problem by uninstalling the local version of matplotlib which was superseding the globally installed version,

$pip3 uninstall matplotlib

Comment: Hello! Would you mind expanding a bit on your answer? E.g. show how to check whether this is the actual problem (check if matplotlib is installed locally and/or globally) and show how you could reinstall it locally. Possibly I'd also include a sentence or two about virtual environments :)