# matplotlib can't find cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying a test code and it can't find cycler
this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,10,4])
plt.ylabel("some numbers")
plt.show()
```

returns the error:

```
ImportError: No module named cycler
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. The error may come from other lines which you didn't show. Maybe check all your `import` line and see if you are trying to import something like `cycler`. That might be the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib relies on cycler. with some versions of matplotlib it was not listed as prerequisite. possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named cycler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197327/importerror-no-module-named-cycler)

try installing cycler, with the same method that you used for matplotlib ideally

```
sudo apt-get python-cycler
```

for instance

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27\matplotlib\artist.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
  File "C:/Python27\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: No module named _path

Comment: How did you install the packages? (both matplotlib and cycler). Please describe the steps with full detail (download from this or that web site, unpacking, building, etc).

Comment: downloaded->went to downloads->unpacked with winzip to python27 folder on acer C:

Comment: This method only works for pure python package. For packages that rely on compiled extensions, the procedure is more complex. You can have a look at http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/intro.html#before-starting-installing-a-working-environment https://scipy.org/install.html or http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try not only to install/reinstall cycler, but also to restart the kernel after (in my case it helped)

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install cycler
```

worked for me!